# R way of merging a list and a named list with fill NA

Tags: r

I have two lists, one without names and one with names where one is a subset of the other. I.e.

```
list1 = c("a", "b", "c")
list2 = c(a=2, c=4)
```

How do I end up with something that looks like:

```
list3 = c(a=2, b=NA, c=4)
```

I know there must be a simple one liner but I don't seem to be able to find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run

```
setNames(list2[list1], list1)
#  a  b  c 
#  2 NA  4
```

The setNames part is required because normally missing values do not have names when subsetting.

Also note that these are named vectors, not named lists (well, list2 is a named vector, list1 is an atomic vector). If you had proper named lists, you'd need to convert the subsetting list to a vector. For example

```
list1 = list("a", "b", "c")
list2 = list(a=2, c=4)

setNames(list2[unlist(list1)], unlist(list1))
```

Comment: nothing can be simpler than yours :D +1!

Answer (score 0):

You could run a conditional loop over the first list then generate (and name) an `NA` for any missing items.

```
for (i in list1){
  if (!i %in% names(list2))
  {
    list3 <- append(list2, NA)
    names(list3)[length(list3)] <- i
    }
}
```